# dbus-monitoring loop exits automatically

Tags: gnome, dbus

**I'm trying to execute a bash command on screen lock/unlock.**

Following tutorials & StackExchange questions, I came up with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; then #added to try to solve the issue, but alas it did not
    dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
    while read sign; do
        case "$sign" in
            *"boolean false"*) echo "Screen unlocked";;
            *"boolean true"*) echo "Screen locked";;
        esac
    done
done
```

I launch the program with the following command:

```
nohup myprogram.sh &
```

**Everything works well at start, but after a while (several hours), there is no more echoed output when screen is locked/unlocked.**

Checking the output of `ps aux | grep mycommand`, I have the following result at start:

```
user  <pid1> 0.0 0.0 <number> <number> pts/2 S 13:01   0.00 /bin/bash myprogram.sh
user  <pid2> 0.0 0.0 <number> <number> pts/2 S 13:01   0.00 /bin/bash myprogram.sh
```

After it breaks and does not emit messages anymore, then the `ps` output only show one line.

I'm using CentOS 6.5, with Gnome 2.28.

Would you have any insight about what could be happening?